# android twitter post code

Tags: android, twitter

#### I tried this code for twitter :

```
    twitter = new Twitter("username","password");
   
    try
    {
        //Status to post in Twitter
        twitter.setStatus(ACCESSIBILITY_SERVICE);
        Toast.makeText(TwitterExample.this, "Article Posted to Twitter  Successfully!!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
    catch(TwitterException.E401 e)
    {
        // comes here when username or password is wrongs 
        Toast.makeText(TwitterExample.this, "Wrong Username or Password,Kindly Check your logins",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
        Toast.makeText(TwitterExample.this, "Network Host not responding",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
```

#### I got this error :

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: main
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: java.lang.String.isEmpty
 at winterwell.jtwitter.URLConnectionHttpClient.processError2_reason(URLConnectionHttpClient.java:442)
 at winterwell.jtwitter.URLConnectionHttpClient.processError(URLConnectionHttpClient.java:365)
 at winterwell.jtwitter.URLConnectionHttpClient.post2(URLConnectionHttpClient.java:303)
 at winterwell.jtwitter.URLConnectionHttpClient.post(URLConnectionHttpClient.java:272)
 at winterwell.jtwitter.Twitter.updateStatus(Twitter.java:2593)
 at winterwell.jtwitter.Twitter.updateStatus(Twitter.java:2519)
 at winterwell.jtwitter.Twitter.setStatus(Twitter.java:2291)
 at org.androidpeople.twitter.TwitterExample.onCreate(TwitterExample.java:24)
 at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
 at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2627)
 at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2679)
 at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2300(ActivityThread.java:125)
 at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2033)
 at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
 at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
 at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4627)
 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
 at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:868)
 at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:626)
 at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Any help much appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: Where you got this error? post error log here.

Comment: Please paste you error log so we can check where exactly you got the error

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're using the [java jar file](http://twitter4j.org/en/twitter4j-2.2.5.zip), rather than the [android jar](http://twitter4j.org/en/twitter4j-android-2.2.5.zip).

Comment: String.isEmpty() doesn't exist in Android, so unless someone broke the implementation of the setStatus method in the Android twitter4j.jar file (I've used the file, but never used that method), you've used the base java implementation rather than the android one.